# Static analysis: Passing pointer to uninitialized data

Tags: variables, pointers, static, code-analysis, initialization

In the past, we've had some trouble with uninitialized data in C-code. I've tried two different static code analysis tools on the code example below. None of them complain about passing a pointer to uninitialized data. Are you aware of any tool that would catch this?

Thank you in advance!

```
static int useByVal(const int int_val) 
{
    return int_val + 1;
}

static void useByRef(int* const int_ptr) 
{
    if (int_ptr != (void*)0) 
    {
        (*int_ptr)++;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    int k;

    /*** GOOD: The tool detects error: Using value of uninitialized automatic object 'i' */
    i = useByVal(i);

    /*** BAD: The tool does not catch uninitialized object 'k' when passed by reference */
    useByRef(&k);

    /*** BAD: Since call to 'useByRef(&k)', the tool now consider 'k' as initialized */
    return i+k;
}
```

Comment: Try http://frama-c.com/ or customize [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) for that.... BTW, using a recent GCC 4.8 with `gcc -Wall -O2` gives warnings on the first 2 mistakes.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know -O2 contributes to raising the warning level in GCC. Will try MELT later when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

No I'm not aware if any tool that would catch that.  The reason is that they usually analyze on a function-by-function basis.  In other words, while analyzing `main` tools would not analyze `useByVal` or `useByRef`, but make reasonable assumptions about them (like they expect an uninitialized object).

Additionally, if they **did** generate messages in this case, then you would need to add comments / pragmas to remove them and say "this usage is OK; don't emit a message any more".  Because of the nature and frequency of pointer-passing, your program would be full of them.

Better implement some dynamic technique and catch the problem during testing.